# In Django, how is the term "app" defined?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

In my Django app, I have a lot of code so I have split up my source files and put them into sub-folders, as follows:

```
myproject/
    myapp/
        management/
            __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py
            common.py
            users.py
            matches.py
        questionnaires/
            demographics/
                templates/
                __init__.py
                models.py
                views.py
            ...
        views/
            __init__.py
            abstract.py
            concrete.py
```

Now I'm confused what to put in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Is it all the folders containing models? Or all the folders containing source? If i include all child folders, do I also need to include the parent folder? Should this match what's in my my `setup.py`'s `packages` argument?

Note: I know I could refactor this into multiple apps, but (1) I would like for all this functionality to have a common namespace since it's being redistributed and (2) I am regardless curious for the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the directory containing the models.py file, that is your "App".  Django uses the models to bind to the database, everything after that is just filler.

The DJango startup is (very slimmed down) as such

#### manage.py

```
# The important part
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "path.to.your.settings")
```

This will define the important pieces, but lets look at the installed

#### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(
   'your.app.name'
)
```

Which basically states, you'll find my `models.py` there and some model definitions (they don't have to be defined, but `models.py` needs to exist)

#### your/app/name/models.py

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    #... model definition ...
    pass
```

Now back to your settings.py

Your source can live ANYWHERE because DJango looks in some very specific locations for certain things, but this is mostly configured in your settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'path.to.urls' # this is the pythonic module path to your `urls.py` file
```

in your `urls.py` file you can define a url such as

```
url(r'^/some/url/def/$', 'some.other.module.handler'),
```

as long as `handler` from `some.other.module` returns a valid HttpResponse object and is on the PYTHONPATH it does not matter where the class lives.

Django has some specifics about management commands, they must live inside your app directory (the same as your model dir) so to define those (if your `model.py` file is inside a different location) you must put them in your data dir

For example I have a project with the following layout

```
/app  
  /data  
     /commands  
        some_command.py
     models.py  
  /app  
     urls.py  
     settings.py
     ...other-source-files...
```

My `settings.py` simple says load the app `data` and point to `app.url` for the url configuration, from that point on it doesn't matter where your source lives (for the most part).

We did this so that our database tables would be named **data_sometablename** vs **app_sometablename** (i was not part of this choice, happened long before i joined)

Comment: Thank you! So does the file need to be called `models.py`? In my example, the dir is called `models` but the files themselves are `matches.py`, etc.

Comment: the directory can have whatever name you deem, the file must be called `models.py`